# Unable to replicate an encryption format from Java to PHP

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

I have the following Java code which was shared by one of an integration partner for their API encryption

```
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.security.AlgorithmParameters;
    import java.security.SecureRandom;
    import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
    import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
    import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
    import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
    import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class AES256 {

    /**
     *
     * @param word
     * @param keyString
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static String encrypt(String word, String keyString) throws Exception {
        byte[] ivBytes;
        //String password = "zohokeyoct2017";
        /*you can give whatever you want for password. This is for testing purpose*/
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte bytes[] = new byte[20];
        random.nextBytes(bytes);
        byte[] saltBytes = bytes;
        System.out.println("salt enc:"+saltBytes.toString());
        // Derive the key
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(keyString.toCharArray(), saltBytes, 65556, 256);
        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
        //encrypting the word
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
        ivBytes = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        byte[] encryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(word.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        //prepend salt and vi
        byte[] buffer = new byte[saltBytes.length + ivBytes.length + encryptedTextBytes.length];
        System.arraycopy(saltBytes, 0, buffer, 0, saltBytes.length);
        System.arraycopy(ivBytes, 0, buffer, saltBytes.length, ivBytes.length);
        System.arraycopy(encryptedTextBytes, 0, buffer, saltBytes.length + ivBytes.length, encryptedTextBytes.length);
        return new Base64().encodeToString(buffer);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param encryptedText
     * @param keyString
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, String keyString) throws Exception {
        //String password = "zohokeyoct2017";
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        //strip off the salt and iv
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new Base64().decode(encryptedText));
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[20];
        buffer.get(saltBytes, 0, saltBytes.length);
        byte[] ivBytes1 = new byte[16];

        buffer.get(ivBytes1, 0, ivBytes1.length);
        byte[] encryptedTextBytes = new byte[buffer.capacity() - saltBytes.length - ivBytes1.length];

        buffer.get(encryptedTextBytes);
        // Deriving the key
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(keyString.toCharArray(), saltBytes, 65556, 256);
        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes1));
        byte[] decryptedTextBytes = null;
        try {
            decryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception"+e);
        }

        return new String(decryptedTextBytes);
    }

    public static void main (String []args) throws Exception{
        String encryptedText;
        encryptedText = AES256.encrypt("106_2002005_9000000106","3264324");
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text:"+encryptedText);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Text:"+AES256.decrypt(encryptedText,"3264324"));

    }
}
```

And I tried couple of PHP codes which I got from stackoverflow or google. COuldnt make any of them working.

The code which I tried lately on PHP is below

```
class AtomAES {

    public function encrypt($data = '', $key = NULL, $salt = "") {
        if($key != NULL && $data != "" && $salt != ""){

            $method = "AES-256-CBC";

            //Converting Array to bytes
            $iv = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
            $chars = array_map("chr", $iv);
            $IVbytes = join($chars);


            $salt1 = mb_convert_encoding($salt, "UTF-8"); //Encoding to UTF-8
            $key1 = mb_convert_encoding($key, "UTF-8"); //Encoding to UTF-8

            //SecretKeyFactory Instance of PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 Java Equivalent
            $hash = openssl_pbkdf2($key1,$salt1,'256','65536', 'sha1'); 

            $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $hash, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $IVbytes);

            return bin2hex($encrypted);
        }else{
            return "String to encrypt, Salt and Key is required.";
        }
    }

    public function decrypt($data="", $key = NULL, $salt = "") {
        if($key != NULL && $data != "" && $salt != ""){
            $dataEncypted = hex2bin($data);
            $method = "AES-256-CBC";

            //Converting Array to bytes
            $iv = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
            $chars = array_map("chr", $iv);
            $IVbytes = join($chars);

            $salt1 = mb_convert_encoding($salt, "UTF-8");//Encoding to UTF-8
            $key1 = mb_convert_encoding($key, "UTF-8");//Encoding to UTF-8

            //SecretKeyFactory Instance of PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 Java Equivalent
            $hash = openssl_pbkdf2($key1,$salt1,'256','65536', 'sha1'); 

            $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($dataEncypted, $method, $hash, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $IVbytes);
            return $decrypted;
        }else{

            return "Encrypted String to decrypt, Salt and Key is required.";

        }
    }

}
```

This is the PHP code which I wanted to try but it doesnt work as expected as per the Java code.

```
Encrypted Text:1HO8iuSZf41RzP/gUleEJY3zhtLJVwFMnhZiphnoG0m9ss+g93Sj5SqQg0D7OsgSvUZCeX2Ck5QPpFrPxM0FE/yFE5s=
Decrypted Text:This is a sample text
KEY: NEWENCTEST
```

Try decrypting the above java encrypted text using the PHP code and the key, if it works then great.

If someone can help me with this it will of a great help!

TIA!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the **Java `encrypt`-method** the (randomly generated) salt- and IV-bytes are copied together with the encryption-bytes in a single byte-array which becomes base64-encoded and which is returned then. In contrast, the **PHP `encrypt`-method** returns a hex-representation of the encryption bytes only. Thus, the information concerning the salt and IV get lost and decryption is no longer possible (unless salt and IV are reconstructed in other ways). In order to prevent this, you have to change the **PHP `encrypt`-method** as follows:

```
public function encrypt($data = '', $key = NULL) {
    if($key != NULL && $data != ""){
        $method = "AES-256-CBC";
        $key1 = mb_convert_encoding($key, "UTF-8"); //Encoding to UTF-8
        //Randomly generate IV and salt
        $salt1 = random_bytes (20); 
        $IVbytes = random_bytes (16); 
        //SecretKeyFactory Instance of PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 Java Equivalent
        $hash = openssl_pbkdf2($key1,$salt1,'256','65556', 'sha1'); 
        // Encrypt
        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $hash, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $IVbytes);
        // Concatenate salt, IV and encrypted text and base64-encode the result
        $result = base64_encode($salt1.$IVbytes.$encrypted);            
        return $result;
    }else{
        return "String to encrypt, Key is required.";
    }
}
```

Now, the parameter `$result` is a base64-encoded string containing the salt, IV and the encryption. By the way, the parameters `$salt1` and `$IVbytes` are also randomly generated now (analogous to the Java `encrypt`-method). Morover the iteration count used for the key generation has been changed from 65536 to 65556 (analogous to the Java `encrypt`-method). Note: Generally, the encrypted text isn't reproducible (even in the case of the same plain text, and the same key/password) due to the random nature of salt and IV.

The **Java `decrypt`-method** decodes the base64-encoded string and then determines the three portions i.e. salt-, IV- and encryption-bytes which are necessary for decryption. The **PHP `decrypt`-method** has to be supplemented with these functionalities:

```
public function decrypt($data="", $key = NULL) {
    if($key != NULL && $data != ""){
        $method = "AES-256-CBC";
        $key1 = mb_convert_encoding($key, "UTF-8");//Encoding to UTF-8
        // Base64-decode data
        $dataDecoded = base64_decode($data);
        // Derive salt, IV and encrypted text from decoded data
        $salt1 = substr($dataDecoded,0,20); 
        $IVbytes = substr($dataDecoded,20,16); 
        $dataEncrypted = substr($dataDecoded,36); 
        // SecretKeyFactory Instance of PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 Java Equivalent
        $hash = openssl_pbkdf2($key1,$salt1,'256','65556', 'sha1'); 
        // Decrypt
        $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($dataEncrypted, $method, $hash, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $IVbytes);
        return $decrypted;
    }else{
        return "Encrypted String to decrypt, Key is required.";
    }
}
```

Now, the parameter `$dataDecoded` contains the decoded base64-encoded string from which salt- (`$salt1`), IV- (`$IVbytes`) and encryption- 
(`$dataEncrypted`) bytes are derived. Morover the iteration count used for the key generation has been changed from 65536 to 65556 (analogous to the Java `decrypt`-method).

**Test case 1: Encrypt and Decrypt with PHP**

```
$atomAES = new AtomAES();
$encrypt = $atomAES->encrypt("This is a text...This is a text...This is a text...", "This is the password");
echo $encrypt; 
$decrypt = $atomAES->decrypt($encrypt, "This is the password");
echo $decrypt;
```

with the result for `$encrypt` (which is in general different for each encryption due to the random nature of salt and IV):

```
6n4V9wqgsQq87HOYNRZmddnncSNyjFZZb8nSSAi681+hs+jwzDVQCugcg108iTMZLlmBB2KQ4iist+SuboFH0bnJxW6+rmZK07CiZ1Ip+8XOv6UuJPjVPxXTIny5p3QptpBGpw==
```

and for `$decrypt`:

```
This is a text...This is a text...This is a text...
```

**Test case 2: Encrypt with Java, Decrypt with PHP**

```
encryptedText = AES256.encrypt("This is a text...This is a text...This is a text...","This is the password");
System.out.println(encryptedText);
```

with the result for `encryptedText` (which is in general different for each encryption due to the random nature of salt and IV):

```
qfR76lc04eYAPjjqYiE1wXoraD9bI7ql41gSV/hsT/BLoJe0i0GgJnud7IXOHdcCljgtyFkXB95XibSyr/CazoMhwPeK6xsgPbQkr7ljSg8H1i17c8iWpEXBQPm0nij9qQNJ8A==
```

and

```
$decrypt = $atomAES->decrypt("qfR76lc04eYAPjjqYiE1wXoraD9bI7ql41gSV/hsT/BLoJe0i0GgJnud7IXOHdcCljgtyFkXB95XibSyr/CazoMhwPeK6xsgPbQkr7ljSg8H1i17c8iWpEXBQPm0nij9qQNJ8A==", "This is the password");
echo $decrypt;
```

with the result for `$decrypt`:

```
This is a text...This is a text...This is a text...
```

**Test case 3: Encrypt with Java, Decrypt with PHP**

```
encryptedText = AES256.encrypt("This is a sample text","NEWENCTEST");
System.out.println(encryptedText);

1HO8iuSZf41RzP/gUleEJY3zhtLJVwFMnhZiphnoG0m9ss+g93Sj5SqQg0D7OsgSvUZCeX2Ck5QPpFrPxM0FE/yFE5s=
```

and

```
$decrypt = $atomAES->decrypt("1HO8iuSZf41RzP/gUleEJY3zhtLJVwFMnhZiphnoG0m9ss+g93Sj5SqQg0D7OsgSvUZCeX2Ck5QPpFrPxM0FE/yFE5s=", "NEWENCTEST");
echo $decrypt;
```

with the result for `$decrypt`:

```
 This is a sample text
```

Comment: This didnt work. I have shared an encrypted string above which was encrypted using java. Try decrypting it with PHP code.

Comment: I had similar issue of not able to replicate java decrypt function to php, thanks to this post  I have replicated function now & its working fine for strings but same isnt working for Image files, I am figuring out what I am missing, any pointer/clue will be help