# Convert Java AES Encryption in PHP code encryption

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt the otp in php. i have the java code that encrypt the otp and when i send that encrypted otp it decrypt at client end as expected. but when i encrypt it using php, decryption does not work.

Actual Java Encryption:

```
public static final String appKey = "wbx+mGnapzZMietP0gK6muJb/vUU7jnAk9Fe5gTHh4w=";    
public static String encryptEK(byte[] plainText, byte[] secret){
        try{
            SecretKeySpec sk = new SecretKeySpec(secret, AES_ALGORITHM);
            ENCRYPT_CIPHER.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk);
            return Base64.encodeBase64String(ENCRYPT_CIPHER.doFinal(plainText));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
    public static String encryptOTP(String otp)
    {
        String encryptedOtp = null;
        try {

            encryptedOtp = encryptEK(otp.getBytes(),decodeBase64StringTOByte(appKey));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptedOtp;
    }
```

> encryptOTP("251826")

Current PhP encryption.

```
    class AtomAES {
     public function encrypt_aps_secret($data = '', $key = NULL) {
            if($key != NULL && $data != ""){
                $method = "AES-256-ECB";
                $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
                $result = base64_encode($encrypted);
                return $result;
            }else{
                return "String to encrypt, Key is required.";
            }
        }
}
    $appKey = mb_convert_encoding("wbx+mGnapzZMietP0gK6muJb/vUU7jnAk9Fe5gTHh4w=", "UTF-8");
    $enc_otp = $atomAES->encrypt_aps_secret("251826", base64_decode(base64_encode($appKey)));
    print_r(json_encode(array("enc_otp"=>mb_convert_encoding($enc_otp, "UTF-8"))));
```

I need the exact encryption as java does using php. how to achieve this

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53765611/unable-to-replicate-an-encryption-method-from-java-to-php-using-aes-ecb-pkcs5pad) will help you out. exactly what you are using

Comment: I have it already and i have used that link for asp encryption it works fine but when i encrypt the opt and send to server server gives me invalid data format. some thing is wrong in encryption technique. for encrypting OTP @saur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
base64_decode(base64_encode($appKey))
```

I believe you use the key in php as string bytes, not as a decoded byte array, try following

```
base64_decode($appKey)
```

It is at least what meets the eye. Still there are other assumptions, such as we can only assume ENCRYPT_CIPHER is `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding`, as well you should create a new Cipher instance every time, as the ENCRYPT_CIPHER may not be thread-safe